# How can I masking cellphone No. on SQL Server to use open-Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had test in Oracle but It doesn't work in Sql server.

Please check this below, And tell me what is the problem.

```
TELNO1 and CELLNO1 has 3 digits
TElNO2 and CELLNO2 has 7~8 digits


+'CASE WHEN (LENGTH(TRIM(TELNO2)) = ''''8'''') THEN '
+'REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(TELNO1), ''''[[:punct:]]''''), ''''( ){1,}'''', '''''''')||''''-''''||REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(TELNO2), ''''[[:punct:]]''''), ''''( ){1,}'''', ''''''''), ''''(.{4})(.{4})'''', ''''\1-****'''') '
+'ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(TELNO1), ''''[[:punct:]]''''), ''''( ){1,}'''', '''''''')||''''-''''||REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(TELNO2), ''''[[:punct:]]''''), ''''( ){1,}'''', ''''''''), ''''(.{3})(.{4})'''', ''''\1-****'''') '
+'END AS TelNo'
+',CASE WHEN (LENGTH(TRIM(CELLNO2)) = ''''8'''') THEN '
+'REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(CELLNO1)||TRIM(CELLNO2), ''''[[:punct:]]''''), ''''( ){1,}'''', ''''''''), ''''(.{3})(.{4})(.{4})'''', ''''\1-\2-****'''') '
+'ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(CELLNO1)||TRIM(CELLNO2), ''''[[:punct:]]''''), ''''( ){1,}'''', ''''''''), ''''(.{3})(.{4})(.{4})'''', ''''\1-\2-****'''') '
+'END AS CELLNo'
```

regular Expression check

Answer (score -1):

That's very complex code to write it down

I tried my best here haha

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    TELNO1 varchar(3),
    TELNO2 varchar(8),
    CELLNO1 varchar(3),
    CELLNO2 varchar(8)
);

INSERT INTO test_table (TELNO1, TELNO2, CELLNO1, CELLNO2)
VALUES ('123', '45678901', '456', '78901234'),
       ('456', '78901234', '789', '01234567'),
       ('789', '01234567', '123', '45678901'),
       ('123', '4567890', '456', '78901234'),
       ('321', '9876543', '654', '32109876'),
       ('111', '1111111', '222', '22222222');

SELECT 
CASE WHEN (LEN(RTRIM(TELNO2)) = 8) THEN 
REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(TELNO1), '[^0-9]', ''), '', '-') + '-' + 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(TELNO2), '[^0-9]', ''), '(.{4})(.{4})', '\1-****'), '', '') 
ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(TELNO1), '[^0-9]', ''), '', '-') + '-' + 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(TELNO2), '[^0-9]', ''), '(.{3})(.{4})', '\1-****'), '', '') 
END AS TelNo,
CASE WHEN (LEN(RTRIM(CELLNO2)) = 8) THEN 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(CELLNO1) + RTRIM(CELLNO2), '[^0-9]', ''), '(.{3})(.{4})(.{4})', '\1-\2-****'), '', '') 
ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(CELLNO1) + RTRIM(CELLNO2), '[^0-9]', ''), '(.{3})(.{4})(.{4})', '\1-\2-****'), '', '') 
END AS CELLNo
FROM test_table;
```

Note: This code uses the LEN function to check the length of the string, and the RTRIM function to remove trailing spaces. The replace function is used to replace non-numeric characters with an empty string and format the phone numbers.

Comment: Sql server REPLACE does not accept any sort of pattern it only accepts exact strings

Comment: Thank you for your reply guys,
I solved that proplem. Just case in case ~ when is wrong.
cause data have nchar, thats why space in right and left of content.
trim can not remove right and left space, only remove in content.
So that was not work.